# IP Forwarding and Routing in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, routing, virtual-machines, ip-forwarding

I have Hyper-V running on a windows 2008. I got a new ip stack from the data center to be set on my virtual machines. But I have difficulties to set these IPs on my VMs because they are on different network.

my current server ip is xxx.xxx.18.6 with MASK : 255.255.255.224 and the GW is xxx.xxx.18.1

my new ip stack is xxx.xxx.168.176/29

I can use RRAS to achieve this.

Do I need to create another NIC? How do I make these VMs reachable from outside?

Comment: The term is "range" not "stack". [IP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_stack) means something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using separate adapters for host and guest access. Create virtual switches and connect them to the "guest" adapters. Connect your guests to the virtual switches. This will establish [layer-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) connectivity between your guests and the switch(es) your *physical* machine is connected to.

All routing should be handled by the upstream router in your datacenter. Check if the guests can ping the default gateway for the new subnet after you configured them with the new IP address.